# Can anyone help me with the following 2.7 Python assignment? [Adding/Sorting List]

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

Write a function called interleave that accepts three lists as arguments and returns one list which is a composite of all three lists. Note that the composite list should be ordered as in the following example: 
If the three lists were

```
x = ['a', 'b']
y = [1, 2]
z = ['orange', 'apple']
```

then the composite list should be

```
['a', 1, 'orange', 'b', 2, 'apple'].
```

You may assume that all the input lists will be of the same length.

I am able to add the the lists; however , I am not able to sort the composite list into the way the assignment asks. The following is what i have so far:

```
x = [ 'a', 'b']
y = [1, 2]
z = [ 'orange', 'apple'] 
composite = []
for element in x, y, z:
    composite.append(element)
print composite
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `itertools`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [list_comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b']
>>> y = [1, 2]
>>> z = ['orange', 'apple']
>>> [j for i in zip(x,y,z) for j in i]
['a', 1, 'orange', 'b', 2, 'apple']
```

To make it as a function.

```
def fun(x,y,z):
    return [j for i in zip(x,y,z) for j in i]
x = ['a', 'b']
y = [1, 2]
z = ['orange', 'apple']
print fun(x,y,z)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `list(itertools.chain(*zip(x,y,z)))` but I think this is far more elegant. +1

Comment: Do you know how I could make this into a function? (: